# Definition of composition of functions $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: general-topology

> (Exercise 2.27 Lee’s Topological Manifolds) Let $C$ be the set
>   $$C =\{(x,y,z)\mid \max\{|x|,|y|,|z|\}=1\}.$$ Show that the continuous map $\varphi :C\to\mathbb{S}^2$ defined by 
>   $$\varphi(x,y,z) = \frac{(x,y,z)} {\sqrt{ x^2+y^2+z^2}},$$
>   is a homeomorphism by showing that its inverse is given by
>   $$\varphi^{-1}(x,y,z) = \frac{(x,y,z)}{\max\{|x|,|y|,|z|\}} \\ = (x,y,z),$$
>   a continuous map.

My confusion is this: obviously, we need to show that $\varphi\circ\varphi^{-1} = \text{id}:C\to\mathbb{S}^2$, although I’m not sure how this is defined since, in each argument, there would be three spacial variables making this a huge headache (as long as this definition is synonymous with the definition of composition for funtions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$). What does he mean?

Comment: You need to show that $\phi^{-1} \circ \phi = \mathrm{id}$ too. Writing the details out in full shouldn't give you a headache and you can make some economies by observing that the problem is symmetric in $x$, $y$ and $z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He means the usual composition. As for the inverse:
Let $(x,y,z) \in S^2$, then:
$$ \varphi^{-1} (x,y,z) = \frac{(x,y,z)}{\max{|x|,|y|,|z|}}  $$
Let $m$ be the max in the denominator:
 Applying $\varphi$ to this, we have:
$$ \varphi \circ \varphi^{-1} (x,y,z) = \varphi \left(\frac{(x,y,z)}{m}  \right) = \frac{(x,y,z)}{m} \left( \frac{x^2}{m^2}+ \frac{y^2}{m^2}+ \frac{z^2}{m^2}\right)^{-1/2} = \frac{(x,y,z)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 +z^2}}$$
But since $x,y,z$ are on the sphere, $x^2 + y^2 +z^2=1$, so:
$$\varphi \circ \varphi^{-1} (x,y,z) = \frac{(x,y,z)}{1} = (x,y,z) $$
So this is the identity. As for dealing with a mess of variables, such is life I suppose.